# Iterating over DB2 table by blocks with no row identifier

Tags: database, db2, spring-jdbc

We must create a process in Spring Framework that reads a DB2 table by blocks.
However, that table does not have a column with an unique identifier that we can use as a cursor, so in second block we don't from which point we must read.
The table has those columns:

```
BOOK_ID  SOLD_AT  QUANTITY
```

The first one is a foreign key to book model, the second one is a date when a book was sold, and the third one the quantity of books sold.

Is it possible to do SELECT ordering by db2's rowId? Unfortunately, this is legacy code so we cannot create an extra column to the db2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select hex(rowid) rowid, t.name, t.creator
from (
select t.*, rid_bit(t) rowid 
from sysibm.systables t
) t 
order by rowid
fetch first 10 row only;
```

[rid_bit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050679.html)(`table-designator`) value for the row may change upon physical row movement (reorg, for example, old row is deleted, new row is inserted into the same physical place, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, then I could select by rowId bigger than a known rowid? Should I use rowid or hex(rowid)? In terms of performance, in a table with lots of entries, could it be a problem using a query like that? Thank you so much

Comment: The function returns `varchar for bit data` value - binary string. If you can work with such a data correctly - use it without hex. You may use `rid()` function instead (it returns `bigint`), if your database is not partitioned (DPF). Sorting a huge table may be not a good idea, but there is no correct alternative to this...